# Windows 10 Auto user login after shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, login, auto-login

My PC, which I keep ON for days, have a scheduled task to turn OFF (shutdown) a certain day of the week. It then turns on automatically after a few hours through BIOS settings. However, it stays on the login screen and doesn't log the user back in. I would like it to login the user while the lock screen remains. I see this happen on my laptop but for the life of me cannot make my desktop do the same. I have tried the usual suspects:

Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options > "Use my sign-in info to...update or restart" > ON
Group Policies > Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Logon Options > "Sign-in and lock...after a restart" > Enabled
Group Policies > Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Logon Options > "Configure the mode...a restart or cold boot" > Always Enabled
With these settings, the system logs-in (and locks) on a restart, but doesn't on a shutdown. I am not sure what else to try.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A shutdown is not. Restart. They are different power states. Your computer is behaving as expected, as you have told it to. You need to rethink your processes.